# Normalized Eigenvectors Maxima

Tags: eigenvector, normalize, maxima

I wa swondering if anyone knows of any function in Maxima to find the normalized eigen vectors of a 21x21 matrix?

I am using the function dgeev but I do not believe these eigenvectors are normalized.

I appreciate Any thoughts,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvectors computed by dgeev are indeed normalized to have Euclidean norm = 1. Keep in mind that to compute the norm of a complex vector (let's call it v), you want

```
sqrt (ctranspose (v) . v)
```

Here ctranspose is the conjugate transpose.

Comment: This is helpful thanks. Is there a function in maxima that can find the norm of my eigenvectors that way I can confirm it is 1. I looked through the manual and the lapack library had some stuff but not what I was looking for.

Comment: @user1558881, there is no built-in function for that. But you can define a function to call `ctranspose` as shown in the previous comment. Or, if you just want to check the matrix of eigenvectors returned by `dgeev`, how about `ctranspose(v) . v` where `v` is the matrix of right eigenvectors returned by `dgeev`. You should find 1.0 on the diagonal (and some other values off the diagonal -- zeros if the original matrix is symmetric).

Answer (score 0):

ueivectors normalizes the eigenvectors but apparently not the eignevlaues

Comment: There would be no point in normalizing eigenvalues.